# Geography puzzles -- find the one-word answer

Tags: word, visual, geography, crosswords, word-search

Below are two separate puzzles, but you will need to solve both to find the one-word answer.

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Nationalism

Completed crossword

> [image]

Completed wordsearch

> [image]

Finally

> Reading the unused letters in the wordsearch backwards gives **TRANSPARENT** which clues overlaying the wordsearch locators on the crossword (the wordsearch is a transparent overlay). This gives the following result
>  [image]
>  Now rearranging the uncrossed letters give NATIONALISM

Thanks to Mathgeek for suggesting overlaying the images in the comments.

2 down in the crossword

> This is about the alphabetical neighbours and not the physical ones.

Comment: Can you explain the 2. of the crossword ? Oh, no need anymore, I wrote the question and suddently I understood ! I think (rot13) vg vf 'arvtuobe' va na nycunorgvp yvfg .

Comment: @Mathgeek I've just realised the term "neighbours" means something different here.

Comment: Could the solution have to do with maybe overlaying the puzzles on each other, hence the a clue?

Comment: You're very close, but that's not the final answer. The missing S was a mistake and I will update the puzzle with a correction.

Comment: @Mathgeek, perhaps yes this would make sense

Comment: Correct! You now have the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the right-hand part:

1. > Arno
2. > Maps
3. > Estate
4. > Congo
5. Not sure about this one / Edit : it is wrong, hexomino has the right answer.

> Crags ?

6. > Area
7. > Land
8. > Won